# How to make label text outlined AND fit the size of the label

Tags: python, pyqt, qlabel, outline

How to make label text to be outlined (for better visibility on transparent Widget) and to be fit into label (as per function setWordWrap (True)? There are examples of how to do one or another, but never both.

Basic example of static label text on transparent widget is:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class Application(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        screen_size = QWidget.screen(self).size()
        screen_width = screen_size.width()
        screen_height = screen_size.height()
        widget_width = screen_width * 0.30


        self.setGeometry(100, 100, widget_width, screen_height)
        self.move(screen_width - widget_width, 0)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TransparentForMouseEvents)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint
                            | Qt.CustomizeWindowHint | Qt.Window)

        l1 = QLabel(self)
        l1.setWordWrap(True)
        l1.setGeometry(0, 0, widget_width, screen_height)
        l1.setFont(QFont('Arial', 22))
        l1.setStyleSheet('color:rgb(0,255,0)')
        l1.setText('Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello')


def render_the_app():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Application()
    window.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
    window.show()


    app.exec_()


render_the_app()
```

This code example will render green color text that is "Hello Hello ..." and renders as:
wrap text example on transparent widget:
[image: wrap text example on transparent widget]

Comment: thank you @eyllanesc for editing the question. I apologize for the same mistake but i could not find out how to make this image look as nice as you did

Comment: Note: I recommend you not to do the same thing again (republish the same post) as the system could block the ability to create a post.

Comment: Got it. Due to limited communication here between the author and reviewers - I still don't know what would happen to other [Closed] post and if someone would ever reopen. I did edit and made it short and clear. Comparing to many other posts I saw on SO I feel after edit mine was at least good enough and better than many. But I can't see if someone reviewed and still did not find it to be good, or no one reviewed it again and I need to wait longer.

Comment: How long ago did you improve your post? Well at most one day, do you think that's a long time? Well no, so you have to learn to be more patient. If you do not want to be patient then analyze your post from the beginning so that it does not end up closed. It is recommended that those who want to make a post take a good time writing (hours) and analyze that they comply with the rules of the site.

Comment: @eyllanesc that is fair point. I was very impressed with the speed of getting the review of the first post (within 15-20 minutes) so after 12+ hours after edit I started to be nervous. Also you know if you are obsessed with some idea but can't find the solution - you may loose your patience. This is not an excuse and I will learn from it. Appreciate your feedback

Comment: @SiarheiHolub it requires less time to close a post than to reopen it: first of all, less privileges (reputation) are required to vote to close a post, as reopening it requires more attention (comparing the modifications and the reasons for the reopening, but not only) and responsibility. Also, viewing new posts is more immediate than reviewing those in the (long) queue of reopen requests. That said, as eyllanesc pointed out, you need to be more patient and try to understand why a post was closed instead of creating a new one that is almost identical to the previous.

Comment: Do note that if the reason for the closure is not clear enough, you can always ask for suggestions in the comment ("I see that the post is closed because it should be more focused, can you tell me what I could do?"). I know that not being able to find a solution is painful, it makes you restless and impatient, but the fact is exactly that: the more you're impatient, the less probabilities that you'll find a solution (on your own or trying to look for help). That said, text painting is *not* an easy task, and what you are asking is not something that can be solved in a matter of minutes.

Comment: @musicamante thank you for detailed explanation. I did not know these many things. And yes, my initial post was quite long and difficult to understand, it was right to close it. Now I hope it is ok. This exact function I try to implement took so many hours/days so first time I tried to ask here and did not know how to do it well ). Now I am better prepared. Hope to make new posts much better

Comment: @SiarheiHolub your post wasn't too long nor difficult. I can't say the reasons for which it was closed, but it's clear to me that your implementation is "too vague" (hence, the "needs to be more focused") than what you're trying to achieve, especially considering that there's no trace of the code in the linked answer in your question, which might justify the "not focused" flag. What you ask is **not** easy, and it also requires very deep knowledge of Qt *and* text drawing. "It looks simple" doesn't imply "it's simple to do it": circles are "simple" but... can you draw a perfect one by hand?

Comment: @musicamante exactly, I thought it will be the easiest part of the project, but ended up to be the most difficult one ). I am not sure if I move in right direction with Qt, but what I try to achieve - is well visible text on transparent widget. Found Qt to be best to me so far to do everything but not this part.

Comment: @musicamante do you know maybe other tool to build something like that, not Qt?

Comment: @SiarheiHolub I don't know what you need for your program, so I cannot nor will give you an answer on that: each application has its requirements, and while a framework can be "adjusted" to your need (assuming that you know it enough to do it), there are many situations for which you should prefer a choice not based on your preference (or knowledge/experience) but on its capabilities. Qt is a highly flexible and extensible framework, but it has it flaws (some of which coincidentally caused by its flexibility and extensibility). You have to choose on your own, as there's no "right" choice.

Comment: [Last comment on the topic, as extended discussions should be avoided in comments, and the matter at hand is quite off-topic for this post] If the most important feature of your program is about the painting (and, possibly, its quality) of the text, then you should probably look for another framework/library/module. If the outlined text is just a (possibly) small part of your project, then I'd suggest you to get more focused on the *whole* project ("the rest of it"), and meanwhile acquire the necessary knowledget to get the outlining done as you wish - which, I'll stress again, is *not* easy.

Comment: @musicamante on a high level - I am building a desktop app for Windows, widget has to be transparent, stay on top of all other windows always, be able to click through so it will not disturb ever regular work. While I press some keys combination - it has to render the text (long or short) like the one in my image attached. I could make everything but the text is hardly visible sometimes if I have behind similar colors. I will keep looking for other solutions

Answer (score 0):

Using a painter path is a fine solution, but it doesn't allow finer control on the contents, especially considering that a text-based widget should also provide correct size hints and, possibly, allow word wrapping.

On the other hand, [QTextDocument](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html), which is used by any QWidget subclass that uses text (sometimes publicly, like QTextEdit, others internally, like QLabel), provides the outline feature, so a possible solution is to create a class that partially mimics a QLabel, providing correct size hints and word wrapping.

```
class Test(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    _outlinePen = _alignment = None
    def __init__(self, text='', parent=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.doc = QtGui.QTextDocument()
        self._reference = self.doc.clone()
        self.doc.contentsChanged.connect(self._rebuildReference)

        self._text = text
        self._outlineColor = QtGui.QColor(kwargs.get('outlineColor'))
        self._outlineWidth = kwargs.get('outlineWidth', 0)

        if text:
            self.doc.setPlainText(text)
            self.updateContents()

    def _rebuildReference(self):
        self._reference = self.doc.clone()

    def updateContents(self):
        cursor = QtGui.QTextCursor(self.doc)
        cursor.select(cursor.Document)
        blockFmt = cursor.blockFormat()
        blockFmt.setAlignment(self.alignment())
        cursor.setBlockFormat(blockFmt)
        charFmt = cursor.charFormat()
        charFmt.setFont(self.font())

        outlinePen = self.outlinePen()
        if outlinePen:
            charFmt.setTextOutline(outlinePen)

        cursor.setCharFormat(charFmt)
        self.updateGeometry()
        self.adjustSize()

    def text(self):
        return self._text

    def setText(self, text):
        if self._text == text:
            return
        self.doc.setPlainText(text)
        self.updateContents()

    def outlinePen(self):
        if isinstance(self._outlineColor, QtGui.QColor) and self._outlineColor.isValid():
            pen = QtGui.QPen(self._outlineColor)
            pen.setWidthF(self._outlineWidth or self.fontMetrics().lineWidth() * .25)
            return pen

    def setOutlinePen(self, pen):
        self._outlineColor = pen.brush().color()
        self._outlineWidth = pen.widthF()
        self.updateContents()

    def outlineColor(self):
        return self._outlineColor

    def setOutlineColor(self, color):
        if self._outlineColor != color:
            self._outlineColor = color
            self.updateContents()

    def outlineWidth(self):
        return self._outlineWidth

    def setOutlineWidth(self, width):
        if self._outlineWidth != width:
            self._outlineWidth = width
            self.updateContents()

    def alignment(self):
        alignment = self._alignment
        if not isinstance(alignment, (QtCore.Qt.Alignment, QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag)):
            alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignTop
            if self.layoutDirection() == QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight:
                alignment |= QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft
            else:
                alignment |= QtCore.Qt.AlignRight
        return alignment

    def setAlignment(self, alignment):
        if self._alignment != alignment:
            self._alignment = alignment
            self.updateContents()

    def changeEvent(self, event):
        if event.type() == event.FontChange:
            self.updateContents()

    def sizeHint(self):
        if self.isVisible():
            doc = self._reference
            doc.setTextWidth(self.width())
        else:
            doc = self.doc
        return doc.size().toSize()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        self._reference.setTextWidth(self.width())
        self._reference.drawContents(qp, QtCore.QRectF(self.rect()))
```

Comment: Thank you! I am very new to PyQt and hardly understand the concept of it. Will test your solution

Comment: I tried with how I understand it but could not make it work. It prints the text, but I could not make it to do wrap or outline. So it gives me black text in one line only.

Comment: I suggest you to try it using my code exactly as it is, without any modifications, in order to see its results. Be aware that the `Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground` attribute might be an issue (I wasn't able to test it). First of all, try it as it is (as a standard widget without the translucent attribute), just to see if the outline works. Then, it's possible that some twicking will be required: translucency implementation is not as "transparent" (pun intended) as it might seem. I strongly suggest you to use a step-by-step approach instead of trying to immediately adapt my code to yours.